# Windows 10 won't boot via UEFI after fresh install

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, installation, uefi

I'm running into a strange issue with a Dell Inspiron 3455 AIO system that came with Windows 10 pre-installed. I started by booting the system up with the existing hard drive to make sure everything worked ok, which it did. I should also note that the system was booting via UEFI w/ Secure Boot out of the box.

I then proceeded to replace that hard drive with a new Samsung 850 EVO SSD, and did a fresh install using a USB drive formatted with the Windows Media Creation Tool. I was able to boot off the USB drive and install Windows without issue. However, upon restart, Windows would not boot. It would just freeze on the Dell logo.

In an attempt to narrow down the issue, I've tried installing Windows using a USB key created with Rufus, installing from a DVD, and installing with Secure Boot off. No matter what I do, Windows will not boot if I install via UEFI, even though the installation finishes without issue every time.

Of course, when I install Windows via CSM/Legacy, everything works fine.

I'm at a loss here. The only thing I can think of is that there is something going on with the Dell BIOS that is preventing this from working. Ultimately, I can just live with CSM, but I'd really like to figure out what's causing this.

Comment: Try reinstalling Windows with Secure Boot on and CSM disabled, then once it reboots to finish installing Windows, go into the BIOS and turn Secure Boot off.

I don't know what the issue is, as I haven't had the time to delve into troubleshooting, however this is an issue with the most recent Windows Update that was pushed around a week ago.  I have an AW18, so it could be an issue with Dell's certificate (either on Dell's side or Microsoft's), or it's an actual bug in the most recent update from around a week ago.  

You can always WIM the old system partition and apply it to the 850 EVO

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just disable Secure Boot and disable CSM.  Sexy Boot is always optional on OEM machines from Dell (required for Dell to sell the machine)

Comment: @Ramhound Doesn't Secure Boot prevent exploits from rootkits?

Comment: @JW0914 The general idea would be to get the installation installed and working then turn it on.  But if your infected with a root kit your infected with malware that loaded that rootkit more then likely.

Comment: @JW0914 I've tried turning off Secure Boot and leaving UEFI on post install and it doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @JW0914 Just to be clear, you're suggesting I image JUST the system partition and apply it to the SSD? Can I use any imaging software (I use Macrium usually) or is WIM a specific type of imaging?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure if I've tried installing it without Secure Boot and UEFI on. Do you think it's worth trying that? Would it have any impact on "how" it installs?

Comment: I would not have suggested it if it wasn't worth doing

Comment: @jyushinx UEFI should be on, Secure Boot off _(at least for testing... I would also try re-downloading the Media Creation tool if you created your install media prior to Tues, as after applying Patch Tuesday's updates, I can now boot again with Secure Boot enabled)_.  No motherboard with UEFI should be installing Windows in CSM mode for a plethora of reasons, the most obvious being performance _(for example, boot times with UEFI ~10s, with CSM ~45s)_.  CSM forces the native 64bit UEFI into legacy 32bit BIOS mode, and the whole point of UEFI is it's 64bit, among other things.

Comment: @jyushinx, specific to your WIM question, Windows has always natively supported full image backups, of which are far better than 3rd party tools for a variety of reasons (too many to incl. in a comment).  With Windows >8, [`DISM`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825258.aspx) would be utilized, whereas with Windows <7, [`ImageX`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx) would be used.   When imaging a Windows system partition, ESD should be used over WIM (`/ImageFile:Z:\Base.esd` & `/Compress:Recovery`).  Full commands in next comment.

Comment: **Create Image:**  `DISM /Capture-Image /ImageFile:Z:\Base.esd /CaptureDir:C: /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2017.07.28" /Compress:Recovery /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:Z:\ `  

**Non-OS partition, change:** _.esd_ to _.wim_ and _/Compress:Recovery_ to _Max_

Comment: **Apply Image:** `DISM /Apply-Image /ImageFile:Z:\Base.esd /Index:1 /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:Z:\ `

_To determine Index (i.e. image # contained within, as ESD & WIM are smart compression images): `DISM /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:Z:\Base.esd`, and for Image # specifics, specify `/Index:<#>` _

Comment: **Add Additional Images:** `DISM /Append-Image /ImageFile:Z:\Base.esd /CaptureDir:C: /Name:"Windows Backup #2" /Description:"2017.07.28" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:Z:\ `

ESD/WIM can contain numerous images _(i.e. most Windows Install.esd's contain 4 images)_, and since they're smart compression images, every additional image added will reuse files that have not been changed in any of the previous images contained within. This allows for ESDs/WIMs to maintain small footprints _(for example, my backup ESD is ~58GB, has 4 images, of which contain over 500GB of files)_.

Comment: **Forgot to annotate:** Windows OS partition can only be imaged in WinPE (_**Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment_, such as a Windows Setup boot media - **press** `SHIFT` **+** `F10` to access terminal) or WinRE (_**Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment_, accessed via _Settings - Update & Security - Recovery -
 Advanced Startup_ or by clicking on the power symbol on the Win Login screen, holding down `SHIFT`, and clicking `Restart`).  _All non-OS partitions can be imaged while booted into Windows (i.e. I have a task that runs every Sunday to append a WIM for my data partition)._

Comment: @JW0914 - why not post an answer? Just put all your comments in a complete answer.

Comment: @snayob Because they're not an answer to the issue posted about, but an answer to the question jyushinx asked in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1235224/windows-10-wont-boot-via-uefi-after-fresh-install?noredirect=1#comment1808592_1235224) comment.  If I had posted them in an answer, the answer would have been down voted (and rightly so).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem attempting to upgrade a family members' Dell 3455 AIO with a new Samsung 850 EVO 500GB SSD.  I have updated to the latest Dell bios v4.3.0 dated March 6, 2018 and have not been successful getting any Win10 install to work, UEFI (secureboot off) or legacy, though the only installation media I had at the time was a UEFI USB drive.  I have only used the samsung cloning software, but am planning to try again in a week or two with an acronis trueimage bootable DVD and may also try the recommended DISM instructions from JW0914.